# Android on NFC read close activity (not the main activity)

Tags: java, android, nfc

does anyone have an idea how to do this:

Lets say, we have an app with 3 activities. Activity 2 has button, which opens simple activity 3 (onClick), and activity 3 shows something like this "Touch NFC". When I touch NFC tag I also need that activity 3 would be finished instantly.

Does anyone have an idea how could I do this

Thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried? What did not work for you? Show some source code, please.

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html and you will find (please read the basic information as a minimum before asking for help dude!)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to edit the AndroidManifest.xml. You should add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

to make sure that your app will have NFC permissions and it wont be installed on a device that lacks NFC hardware.

Next, you should add intent filters, so that your app will be called after a tag is detected:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

This is a simple example, and it wont necessairly work with every type of tag and data stored on it. Eventually, you will have to do your own research.

Now you just have to handle the tag discovered in your activity. It will look similar to

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction()))
         activity.finish() //you wanted to close an activity, right?
```

What you put in here depends on what you want to do. Poke the problem a bit, play with it, then do what you need done.

On a side note - please read the SO FAQ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. The very first paragraph asks you to do your homework. Dont expect the community to write the entire code for you while you cant be bothered to even type your problem into google. Also, if this is a homework assignment - please tag it as one.

For further reading: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html - here you can find all the information you need to complete your task.